# Finding volume of a sphere using integration

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, circles, spheres

I have searched and found 2 methods of finding volume using integration :

- considering a small cylindrical element and integrating that over the radius
- considering a small circle element and using the relation `x^2 + y^2 = r^2` and integrating it over the `z-axis`.

I was trying to find the integration by considering a small circle element (with radius r) and using the relation `r = R cosθ` where `R` is the radius of the sphere / hemisphere.

So I was thinking of calculating the volume of the hemisphere by integrating the `π R^2 cos^2θ dθ` from `0` to `π/2`. Is this method right? And how will the integration be like?

Answer (score 1):

The best way of solving this problem it's using spherical coordinates. Then, you can only calculate the volume of one octant of the space supposing that the sphere is centered on the origin.

So, given a solid sphere with radius $R$, the volume would be:

$$
V = 8 \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{d\theta}\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\int_{0}^{R}{r^{2}\sin{\varphi}\,\,dr}d\varphi}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I do not like the "consider a small element" approach physicists often use, as it is not very intuitive and can easily produce errors. In this case you can just use the usual transformation of integrals: $\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}$

$$ \int_{\Omega} f(y) dy = \int_{\phi^{-1}(\Omega)} f(\phi(x)) |\det D\phi(x)| dx $$

Where $\varphi : \Omega \to \phi(\Omega) \subseteq \mathbb R^{n}$ is transformation of the coordinate systems and $D\phi : \Omega \to \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is the corresponding Jacobi matrix.

So in your case all you have to do is set $f:\equiv 1$ and write down your transformation $\phi$. Then $|\det D\phi(x)|$ is the expression you are looking for, and the above equation simplifies to

$$Vol(\Omega) = \int_{\Omega} 1dy = \int_{\phi^{-1}(\Omega)} |\det D\phi(x)| dx $$

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but I was looking for a method to proceed with what  I have, not a completely different method. Any help in this regard?

Comment: This is not a completely different method, you did make a change of coordinates, you just have to plug that in for $\phi$ in $|\det D\phi|$ to find out what you want.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. My knowlege of matrix is very little, so I didn't understand your answer. Just saw you used dx instead of dθ and assumed it was different

Comment: You can find an extensive derivation here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx But I think at the very least knowledge of the transformation formula is essential when it comes to multi dimensional integration.

Answer (score 0):

Spherical co-ordinates are perfect for this

$$\int^{2\pi}_{0}\int^{\pi}_{0}\int^{r}_{0}r^2\cdot \sin(\phi)\cdot dr\cdot d\phi \cdot d\theta$$

you may find the following document an interesting read:
https://sites.math.washington.edu/~aloveles/Math324Fall2013/f13m324TripleIntegralExamples.pdf